# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Jupyter Notebook on Amazon EMR

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, mysql-connector

While trying to connect to MySql database in RDS from EMR Jupyter Notebook, I have found the following error :

Code Used:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
hostname="hostname"
dbname = "mysql"
jdbcPort = 3306
username = "user"
password = "password"
jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}".format(hostname,jdbcPort, dbname,username,password)
query = "(select * from framework.File_Columns) as table1"
df1 = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',url=jdbc_url, dbtable=query ).load()
df1.show()
```

Error message:

> An error occurred while calling o89.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-37-50.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I have downloaded the required `mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar` to `/home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar` and have updated the Spark configuration file as follows:

```
spark.master                     yarn

spark.driver.extraClassPath      :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*:/home/hadoop/extrajars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar

spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*:/home/hadoop/extrajars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar

spark.executor.extraClassPath    :/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*:/home/hadoop/extrajars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar

spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*:/home/hadoop/extrajars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar
```

Is there anything more that I have to do, so as to connect to the MySql DB from the Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's unable to find driver class when you are running it from Jupyter Notebook, to avoid that you can try by copying `mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar` to the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder. It will resolve your driver issue as per my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :

```html
spark.conf.set("jars", "s3://bucket-name/folder-name/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar")
```